# Calculate the percent of two SUM in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, crosstab

Currently, I have two rows of data placed in a cross tab, and at the bottom of those rows they are summed up. I have a third row that is supposed to get the percentage of the sum of those two rows, but it does not due to the fact that it uses a different formula entirely and the actual result comes out wrong.

```
Eg. <br>
Row 1<br>
Header - In time (the words below are NOT in the row)<br>
489.7 minutes<br>
369.0 minutes<br>
296.5 minutes<br>
312.8 minutes<br>
423.9 minutes<br>
1,892.1 total minutes
```

Sum formula for In Time Total:

```
if {databasefield.InTime} > 0 then {databasefield.InTime} /60000 else 0<br>

Row 2<br>
Header - Running Time<br>
253.3 minutes<br>
173.1 minutes<br>
135.6 minutes<br>
124.2 minutes<br>
160.4 minutes<br>
828.6 total minutes<br>
```

Sum formula for Running Time Total:

```
if {databasefield.RunningTime} > 0 then {databasefield.RunningTime} /60000 else 0<br>

Row 3<br>
Header - percentage<br>
48.05 %<br>
46.90 %<br>
45.74 %<br>
39.71 %<br>
37.84 %<br>
44.20 % total (incorrect value) <br>
```

I technically need it to divide the Running Time / In time

Sum formula for Percentage Total:

```
if Sum ({@InTime}, {database.username}) > 0 then 
  formula = {@RunningTimeformula} / Sum ({@InTime}, {database.username}) *100 
else 
  formula = 0 
end if
```

In this case, RunningTimeForumula is:

```
formula = (sum({databasefield.RunningTime},{databasefield.username}))/60000
```

That above said, I cannot find out how to just divide the sum value of the two totals.

Comment: Due to my work on CR, When i need tp place percentages in a cross tab I get them caculated from my procedure and place them as a column. I use no formulas in the report.

Comment: Hmm, in this case I do not know enough of Crystal Reports to be able to visualize (let alone recreate this report) creating a column in the summarized fields that will create the percentage of the other two summarized fields.